# NSDATE in ios with time zone

Tags: nsdate, nsdateformatter

i have a string 2013-03-17 08:41:16 +0000 i want to convert that into  something like this Sun Feb 24 2013 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time) iam successful in getting like this Feb 24 2013 00:00:00 GMT 0530 India Standard Time .but i want the plus sign and brackets to be there .Any  help willbe highly appreciated thanks. I have tried the following

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter=[NSDateFormatter new];
        [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss z"];
        NSDate *date=[dateFormatter dateFromString:txtStartDate.text];

        [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEE MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss +zzz (zzzz)"];
        NSLog(@"%@",[dateFormatter stringFromDate:date]);

        startDate = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[dateFormatter stringFromDate:date]];
```